Converted nested Json array into relational csv file
Develop a utility that takes any JSON input and converts it into a flattened tabular format with rows and columns. The utility should handle nested arrays and objects, transforming them into a structure that can be easily analyzed or imported into relational databases.
And if there are two values in a nested array that should me moved into two new columns.
Current code flattens everything into rows.
`from typing import Final, Dict, Tuple
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame as SDF
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, ArrayType

def rename_dataframe_cols(df: SDF, col_names: Dict[str, str]) -> SDF:
    """
    Rename all columns in dataframe
    """
    return df.select(*[col(col_name).alias(col_names.get(col_name, col_name)) for col_name in df.columns])

def update_column_names(df: SDF, index: int) -> SDF:
    df_temp = df
    all_cols = df_temp.columns
    new_cols = dict((column, f"{column}*{index}") for column in all_cols)
    df_temp = df_temp.transform(lambda df_x: rename_dataframe_cols(df_x, new_cols))

    return df_temp

def flatten_json(df_arg: SDF, index: int = 1) -> SDF:
    """
    Flatten Json in a spark dataframe using recursion
    """
    # Update all column names with index 1
    df = update_column_names(df_arg, index) if index == 1 else df_arg

    # Get all field names fron the dataframe
    fields = df.schema.fields

    # For all columns in the dataframe
    for field in fields:
        data_type = str(field.dataType)
        column_name = field.name

        first_10_chars = data_type[0:10]
    
        # If it is an Array column
        if first_10_chars == 'ArrayType(':
            # Explode Array column
            df_temp = df.withColumn(column_name, explode_outer(col(column_name)))
            return flatten_json(df_temp, index + 1)

        # If it is a json object
        elif first_10_chars == 'StructType':
            current_col = column_name
            
            append_str = current_col

            # Get data type of current column
            data_type_str = str(df.schema[current_col].dataType)

            # Change the column name if the current column name exists in the data type string
            df_temp = df.withColumnRenamed(column_name, column_name + "#1") \
                if column_name in data_type_str else df
            current_col = current_col + "#1" if column_name in data_type_str else current_col

            # Expand struct column values
            df_before_expanding = df_temp.select(f"{current_col}.*")
            newly_gen_cols = df_before_expanding.columns

            # Find next level value for the column
            begin_index = append_str.rfind('*')
            end_index = len(append_str)
            level = append_str[begin_index + 1: end_index]
            next_level = int(level) + 1

            # Update column names with new level
            custom_cols = dict((field, f"{append_str}->{field}*{next_level}") for field in newly_gen_cols)
            df_temp2 = df_temp.select("*", f"{current_col}.*").drop(current_col)
            df_temp3 = df_temp2.transform(lambda df_x: rename_dataframe_cols(df_x, custom_cols))
            return flatten_json(df_temp3, index + 1)

    return df`

